# Averaging dstat output

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, netstat

I need to average upload and download speed using dstat -n. How can I add all the received and sent datas that appear after dstat -n , so that I can add them and find average upload and download speed over some period of time

Answer (score 0):

As no one answered,I have figured it out. Here is how to do it. Let's say we need to average it for "2 min(120 sec)". First write it to a file named stat.txt.Refresh every second fro 120 times.

```
dstat -n 1 120 >> stat.txt
```

Add the columns of stat.txt

```
awk -F" " '{t1=t1+$1;t2=t2+$2}END{t1=t1/120;t2=t2/120;print t1"\t"t2}' stat.txt
```

Remove stat.txt

```
rm stat.txt
```

We can make a script too from these commands.